# How to calculate user selections when stored in powers of 2?

Tags: checkbox, user-input

For demonstration, I have 6 options for users to choose from:

- Option 1 = 1
- Option 2 = 2
- Option 3 = 4
- Option 4 = 8
- Option 5 = 16
- Option 6 = 32

My users select these random combinations with the resulting values:

- Options 1, 4 and 6 (1 + 8 + 32 = 41)
- Options 2, 3 and 4 (2 + 4 + 8 = 14)
- Options 3 and 5 (4 + 16 = 20)

**Questions:**

- What is this "method" called?
- If given a number, say 56, what is the most efficient calculation to determine the options that were selected?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit mask. Usually, you'd bitwise `or` them together, rather than adding. To check for a specific option being set, mask the bit by `and`ing with the value of the option, and checking for a non-zero result.